# SharePoint access via Reverse Proxy - 500 Internal Server Error while uploading document

Tags: 2013, alternate-access-mapping, reverse-proxy

I configured a SharePoint 2013 server to be accessible through a reverse proxy by doing relevant changes in Alternate Access Mappings. I am able successfully login via the reverse proxy and perform other tasks like viewing calendar, adding tasks, viewing documents etc.

However, when I try to add a new document, it fails. After little investigation I found that when I click on the Add New Document button, there a 500 Internal Server Error for the corresponding GET request to upload.aspx.

Currently I have no clue how to resolve this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the subcode for the HTTP 500? You'll find this in IIS logs.

Comment: What reverse proxy is that? I've seen ISA do this with when dealing with extended chars in URL, but it was long time ago. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/940248

Comment: @AzizKabyshev It is OpenIG (http://openig.forgerock.org/).

@TrevorSeward Can you please tell me where does to IIS log reside? I checked `C:\Program files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS` but there are so many files I am lost.

Comment: @SoumyaKanti IIS logging is documented [here](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/sitedefaults/logfile). Please find corresponding logging directory, reproduce the error, and look for lines that contain both `upload.aspx` and `500`. Add that to the question

Comment: @AzizKabyshev Thanks for the info, I have been able to locate the IIS logs. However, after reproducing the scenario, I did not find any entry in the log file for `upload.aspx` or `500 Internal Server Error`. When I match the call flow with that of at the Network  panel of the browser, I can see logs for preceding and following exchanges that were successful. Very strange! I tried both W3C and IIS logging formats.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment:

> I did not find any entry in the log file for `upload.aspx` or `500 Internal Server Error`. When I match the call flow with that of at the Network panel of the browser, I can see logs for preceding and following exchanges that were successful.

IMO, this most likely shows your **reverse proxy is the reason**. Long time ago ISA Server was known to fail to handle extended chars in URLs and show misleading HTTP 500.

What you can do:

1. Diagnose further with [IIS Failed Request Tracing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kishorerajendran/2015/05/08/failed-request-tracing-iis/) turned on
2. [Change HTTP 500 error page](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2012/05/02/custom-error-pages-http-error-500-19-internal-server-error/) in IIS at SharePoint and reproduce to see if 500 you are seeing is 500 from SharePoint
3. Update reverse proxy solution bits to the latest available, test once more and if that fails - create a ticket with its helpdesk

I'd do #3.